# How to hide hud/GUI

Tags: clash-of-clans

I was wondering if you could hide the buttons on screen (gui) in clash of clans.

I’ve already tried looking it up and I’ve looked in settings on the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I couldn't find any information on the wiki, app, or anywhere online. So I contacted support and asked your exact question in the title. Here is the response: [image: Email To Clash]

So it seems the only thing you can hide the HUD for is taking screenshots.

Comment: That’s fine that’s why I asked anyway.

Comment: Glad to hear it! @Corsair4Life